# warning in git and github about permission denied

Tags: windows, git, git-status

```
$ git status
warning: could not open directory '$RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-18/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory '$RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-1320611954-3689187021-1978721250-1002/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'System Volume Information/': Permission denied
```

On branch main

No commits yet

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
```

my git repository was not running

Comment: sounds like a windows issue

Comment: This has nothing to do with Javascript, HTML, CSS or ReactJs. Please tag your questions appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

The user you are testing with has no permission to load a few directories inside a git repository and this errors out `git status`.

You can grant permissions to the user you are to use git with to the folders in question.

Or you could run your terminal as administrator.

Or you could add those folders to .gitignore, commit and try again, via:

```
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "Ignored some folders"
git status
```

but make sure you added the folders properly before committing and getting the status.